# Open jQuery ColorBox automatically on page load

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have used the colorbox jQuery lightbox for my lightbox. But in that one should click the button. I want automatically popup whenever the window is loaded.

My code for light box is

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".ajax").colorbox();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Other Content Types</h2>
        <p><a class='ajax' href="../content/daisy.jpg" title="Homer Defined">Outside HTML (Ajax)</a></p>
</html>
```

Now I want to an automatic popup when the window is loaded.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With the latest version of [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox), you use `$.colorbox({inline:true, href:".ajax"});`
Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/34v22/

I also cleaned up your code a bit:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>My Automatic ColorBox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../link/to/jquery.colorbox.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script>$(document).ready(function(){$.colorbox({inline:true, href:".ajax"});});</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Other Content Types</h2>
    <div class='ajax' style='display:none'><a href="../content/daisy.jpg" title="Homer Defined">Outside HTML (Ajax)</a></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked, but i am not able to click on on the iframe page. I've put a form in the iframe.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(){$.colorbox({inline:true, href:".ajax"});});
</script>

<script>
(function($){
       $(document).ready(function() {
             $.colorbox({innerWidth:600,innerHeight:500,html:'<iframe width=600 height=500 
                    src=masson-form.html>  </iframe>'});
                });
         })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like, you can add your html directly in the jQuery call

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.colorbox({innerWidth:420,innerHeight:315,html:'<iframe width=420 height=315 src=http://www.youtube.com/embed/eh-0knDpn5g frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>'});
    });
})(jQuery);
```