# How to create an overlay login box

Tags: php, css, overlay

I want to create an overlay page containing login box which comes up automatically every time an user is not logged in. I am doing my codes in php. I just want to show a shaded image of the page with a login box over it. User can't enter the site without login.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Where's your code that didn't work as expected? Have you even looked up how to do this before asking?

Comment: thanx for the quick reply. Btw I have ben working hard over it but as i m just a beginner i m not able to get the desired result.

Comment: Of course, it's just that generally most of us answering questions on this site are working programmers trying to give back. At the end of the day fixing code is the general concept of this site, so when there's no code to fix and only a question most people will downvote your question. Come back with the code of your login page that isn't working as expected and I'm happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a modal box that is loaded by a conditional $user->loggedin type statement. It also sounds like you have limited experience working with these before, so I suggest you start with colorbox for your modal box. http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

If you wanted to show a shaded login image, you could do something like

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id='loginImgContainer'>
  <div id='loginFilter'></div>
  <img src="images/login.jpg" alt="" id="loginImg">
  <div id='loginArea'>
      <!-- my log in form -->
  </div>
</div>

<!-- CSS -->
<style>
#loginImgContainer { 
  position: relative; 
}
#loginFilter {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
#loginArea { display:none; }
</style>
```

Then, set some javascript to detect for a focus on the modal box

```
<script>
//assumes you have jQuery enabled
jQuery( document ).ready( function($) {
    //listen for the click
    $( "#loginImgContainer" ).click( function(e) {
        //hide the login image overlay
        $( "#loginFilter" ).fadeOut( 300 );
        setTimeout( function(){
            //hide the login img background
            $( "#loginImg" ).hide( 0 );
            //show the login form
            $( "#loginArea" ).fadeIn( 500 );
        }, 300 );
    });
});
</script>
```

Say you have a function in php called user_is_logged_in() which returns a boolean response, you could append this to your script tag:

```
<?php
if( user_is_logged_in() ):
    //see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778561/open-jquery-colorbox-automatically-on-page-load> for details on this
    ?>
    $.colorbox({inline:true, href:".ajax"});
    <?php
endif;
```

Then just edit to your needs and add the login form where I denoted to above.

Answer (score 0):

first make a session that used for checking the user logged in or not. $_SESSION['logedin']
then :

if(!isset($_SESSION['logedin']))
  echo "PUT UR LOGIN FORM HERE'";

and add this style :

```
<style>
.login{
width:400px;
height:200px;
position:absolute;
z-index:1000;
background-color:#ccc;
border:#999 thin solid;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not easy reply with no code to work on... anyway you can start from here:

```
if(!$user->loggedIn()){
        redirect('/#box');
}
```